# Google Analytics inside facebook application

Tags: facebook, google-analytics, facebook-apps

I've a problem with google Analytics inside Facebook application. Everything works fine except tracking the source. Always the source is 'apps.facebook.com'. I was trying with Google tags and campaign, but did not work.

Do you have any solution for me?